# Do followers use ammo for a new gun?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

If I gave Cass a 12-gauge shotgun to replace the one she currently uses, which is a 20gauge, would I need to give her 12-gauge ammo for her to use it? Would she use up that ammo?

Comment: Followers used ammo? It's been a while since I played, but I don't think followers ever used ammo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Followers have [Magical Companion Ammo](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_companion_ammo) for their default guns, but if you want them to use any other weapons, you'll need to supply them with ammo.

They will also [stop using a weapon if it breaks](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_companions#Weapons), according to the wiki. However other sources online report that companion's weapons won't break and that you should use surplus ammo for them to save caps. I never game my companions other weapons so I can't confirm or refute this.

Answer (score 1):

They need to be given ammo for the new weapon and they do degrade over time. Unless you are getting the 50% companion damage bonus from 10 charisma though their default weapons are generally the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you can you a weapon that uses the same ammunition and the ammunition perk still applies hope it helps